# how to move one page to another in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

could you please tell me why I am not able to navigate one page to another on button click .
I do like that

```
var loginCntrl=function($scope,$location){
  $scope.testClick =function(){
    alert('sss');
     $location.path("/no");


  }

$scope.name="naveen";
$scope.lastname="sharam";
$scope.fullname = function() {
    return $scope.firstname + $scope.lastname;
};
}
```

here is plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/gQcXe0Njvx6Iviu8Fjep?p=preview

I want to go on second page .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using ui-router you should be using `$state` to transfer from page to page. You should inject `$state` into your controller, then you can use `$state.go('appaa')` to transfer to that state.

See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options for more information.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/gQcXe0Njvx6Iviu8Fjep?p=preview Please check I used Go but not work

Comment: done, also added a controller and views to your second state, might come in handy ;) http://plnkr.co/edit/xiZkLbBcZkoV28XmFeYG?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for answer I understand the things http://plnkr.co/edit/NBNOPS76DvUI1AfPxxnA?p=preview .But there is mistake in "Test Come" display on bottom

Comment: Problem is on this line parent:'b',

Comment: could you please check when if I don't need "test come" on bottom How I will achieve that ?

Comment: That's really out of context for this question, frankly it's an entirely different question and that's not what comments are meant for. Just post a new question so that everyone can help out.

Answer (score 0):

Not that much clear your question. Might you are try to make single page app using AngularJS.
We can create many HTML pages and call in single page without refreshing the page using AngularJS  `$routeProvider` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider).

Find the below Example

1) Create three html pages home.html, about.html, services.html and save in 'pages' folder.

2) Create JS and add below script and save in 'js' folder (js/script.js).

```
var shanidkvApp = angular.module('shanidkvApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure routes

spaApp.config(function($routeProvider) {   
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html'
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/about.html'
        })
        .when('/services', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/services.html'
        });
});
```

3) Create a index page and call angular.min.js, script.js

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="spaApp">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>AngularJS Routing</h1>
        <ul class="menu"> 
            <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/services">Services</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="contentwrap" ng-view>Loading...</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Download working example from Github](https://github.com/shanidkv/AngularJS-Basic-single-page-application)